# How to create a Markdown table of contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, markdown, tableofcontents

I want to create a table of contents from a markdown file in next.js and I want it to be in markdown format as well.

To achieve that I have made this function:

```js
const getMarkdownTOC = (slug) => {
  const folder = process.env.PATH_ARTICULOS
  const file = `${folder}${slug}.md`
  const content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
  const matterResult = matter(content)

  let prevLevel = 99
  let spaces = ''
  let toc = ''
  for (const [, value] of Object.entries(compiler(matterResult.content).props.children)) {
    if (value.type !== undefined && value.type.startsWith('h') && !isNaN(value.type[1])) {
      const level = Number(value.type[1])
      const title = value.props.children[0]
      const id = value.props.id

      if (level > prevLevel) {
        spaces += '  '
      } else {
        if (level < prevLevel) {
          spaces = spaces.slice(0, spaces.length - 2 * (prevLevel - level))
        }
      }
      toc += `${spaces}* [${title}](#${id})\n`
      prevLevel = level
    }
  }
```

And the function does actually work, it returns a table of contents in markdown format that can be rendered wherever I want.
However, I think there has to be some easier way to achieve that, but I've been searching and haven't found anything. There is a plugin called [remark-toc](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-toc) which is almost what I want, but it seems to create the table of contents at the beginning of the document and I want to keep it apart.

Any ideas? Thank you!